# How to use Autofac as DI container in Avalonia.ReactiveUI?

Tags: c#, autofac, reactiveui, avaloniaui

I am trying to override the DI container used in Avalonia and ReactiveUI with Autofac. So far I have tried following the [instructions in the `Splat.Autofac` repository](https://github.com/reactiveui/splat/blob/main/src/Splat.Autofac/README.md), but I can't get Avalonia to work.

As a working example, I took the [HelloWorld example from the ReactiveUI.Samples](https://github.com/reactiveui/ReactiveUI.Samples/tree/main/avalonia/hello-world/HelloWorld) repository.

I could think of two places to override Splat. In `App.xaml.cs` in the `OnFrameworkInitializationCompleted` method:

```
using System.Reflection;

using Autofac;

using Avalonia;
using Avalonia.Markup.Xaml;
using Avalonia.ReactiveUI;
using Avalonia.Threading;

using ReactiveUI;

using Splat;
using Splat.Autofac;

namespace ReactiveAvalonia.HelloWorld {
    public class App : Application {
        public override void Initialize() {
            AvaloniaXamlLoader.Load(this);
        }

        public override void OnFrameworkInitializationCompleted()
        {
            // Build a new Autofac container.
            var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
            builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()).AsImplementedInterfaces();

            // Use Autofac for ReactiveUI dependency resolution.
            // After we call the method below, Locator.Current and
            // Locator.CurrentMutable start using Autofac locator.
            AutofacDependencyResolver resolver = new AutofacDependencyResolver(builder);
            Locator.SetLocator(resolver);

            // These .InitializeX() methods will add ReactiveUI platform 
            // registrations to your container. They MUST be present if
            // you *override* the default Locator.
            Locator.CurrentMutable.InitializeSplat();
            Locator.CurrentMutable.InitializeReactiveUI();

            var container = builder.Build();
            resolver.SetLifetimeScope(container);
        }
    }
}
```

But when running this, the startup fails with the following exception:

> System.ArgumentException: 'Don't know how to detect when ReactiveAvalonia.HelloWorld.MainView is activated/deactivated, you may need to implement IActivationForViewFetcher'

My other idea was to do the overriding in `Program.cs`'s `Main`:

```
using System.Reflection;

using Autofac;

using Avalonia;
using Avalonia.Controls;
using Avalonia.Logging.Serilog;
using Avalonia.ReactiveUI;
using Avalonia.Threading;

using ReactiveUI;

using Splat;
using Splat.Autofac;

namespace ReactiveAvalonia.HelloWorld {

    // You may want to start here:
    // https://reactiveui.net/docs/getting-started/

    class Program {
        // http://avaloniaui.net/docs/reactiveui/
        // https://github.com/AvaloniaUI/Avalonia/wiki/Application-lifetimes
        public static AppBuilder BuildAvaloniaApp() {
            return AppBuilder
                .Configure<App>()
                .UseReactiveUI()
                .UsePlatformDetect()
                .LogToDebug();
        }

        private static void AppMain(Application app, string[] args) {
            app.Run(new MainView());
        }

        public static void Main(string[] args) {
            // Build a new Autofac container.
            var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
            builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()).AsImplementedInterfaces();

            // Use Autofac for ReactiveUI dependency resolution.
            // After we call the method below, Locator.Current and
            // Locator.CurrentMutable start using Autofac locator.
            AutofacDependencyResolver resolver = new AutofacDependencyResolver(builder);
            Locator.SetLocator(resolver);

            // These .InitializeX() methods will add ReactiveUI platform 
            // registrations to your container. They MUST be present if
            // you *override* the default Locator.
            Locator.CurrentMutable.InitializeSplat();
            Locator.CurrentMutable.InitializeReactiveUI();

            var container = builder.Build();
            resolver.SetLifetimeScope(container);

            BuildAvaloniaApp().Start(AppMain, args);
        }
    }
}
```

But this fails with another exception:

> System.Exception: 'Container has already been built and the lifetime scope set, so it is not possible to modify it anymore.'

What can I do to get this to work?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Normally, the Avalonia docs tell you to use the [`UseReactiveUI` extension method](https://github.com/AvaloniaUI/Avalonia/blob/master/src/Avalonia.ReactiveUI/AppBuilderExtensions.cs#L15) on the `AppBuilder` to be able to use ReactiveUI. What this does is registering some Avalonia components to the DI container:

```
    public static TAppBuilder UseReactiveUI<TAppBuilder>(this TAppBuilder builder)
        where TAppBuilder : AppBuilderBase<TAppBuilder>, new()
    {
        return builder.AfterPlatformServicesSetup(_ =>
        {
            RxApp.MainThreadScheduler = AvaloniaScheduler.Instance;
            Locator.CurrentMutable.RegisterConstant(new AvaloniaActivationForViewFetcher(), typeof(IActivationForViewFetcher));
            Locator.CurrentMutable.RegisterConstant(new AutoDataTemplateBindingHook(), typeof(IPropertyBindingHook));
        });
    }
```

With the two solutions in the question, there are two possible ways things go wrong:

### Setting up Autofac in `App`

When you set up Autofac in `OnFrameworkInitializationCompleted`, this happens *after* the registrations setup in `UseReactiveUI` are made, essentially overriding them.

If you add those lines of code again after overriding the DI container, the application boots:

```
    public override void OnFrameworkInitializationCompleted()
    {
        // Build a new Autofac container.
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
        builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()).AsImplementedInterfaces();

        // Use Autofac for ReactiveUI dependency resolution.
        // After we call the method below, Locator.Current and
        // Locator.CurrentMutable start using Autofac locator.
        AutofacDependencyResolver resolver = new AutofacDependencyResolver(builder);
        Locator.SetLocator(resolver);

        // These .InitializeX() methods will add ReactiveUI platform 
        // registrations to your container. They MUST be present if
        // you *override* the default Locator.
        Locator.CurrentMutable.InitializeSplat();
        Locator.CurrentMutable.InitializeReactiveUI();

        Locator.CurrentMutable.RegisterConstant(new AvaloniaActivationForViewFetcher(), typeof(IActivationForViewFetcher));
        Locator.CurrentMutable.RegisterConstant(new AutoDataTemplateBindingHook(), typeof(IPropertyBindingHook));
        RxApp.MainThreadScheduler = AvaloniaScheduler.Instance;

        var container = builder.Build();
        resolver.SetLifetimeScope(container);
    }
```

### Setting up Autofac in `Main`

Here we have overridden the DI container already before Avalonia attempts to register its components, at this time, the Autofac container is already created though, and with it being read-only, that causes the second exception. Again this can be fixed by making those same registrations along with the other code. Then the `AppBuilder.UseReactiveUI` extension method can be omitted:

```
using System.Reflection;

using Autofac;

using Avalonia;
using Avalonia.Controls;
using Avalonia.Logging.Serilog;
using Avalonia.ReactiveUI;
using Avalonia.Threading;

using ReactiveUI;

using Splat;
using Splat.Autofac;

namespace ReactiveAvalonia.HelloWorld {

    // You may want to start here:
    // https://reactiveui.net/docs/getting-started/

    class Program {
        // http://avaloniaui.net/docs/reactiveui/
        // https://github.com/AvaloniaUI/Avalonia/wiki/Application-lifetimes
        public static AppBuilder BuildAvaloniaApp() {
            return AppBuilder
                .Configure<App>()
                //.UseReactiveUI()
                .UsePlatformDetect()
                .LogToDebug();
        }

        private static void AppMain(Application app, string[] args) {
            app.Run(new MainView());
        }

        public static void Main(string[] args) {
            // Build a new Autofac container.
            var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
            builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()).AsImplementedInterfaces();

            // Use Autofac for ReactiveUI dependency resolution.
            // After we call the method below, Locator.Current and
            // Locator.CurrentMutable start using Autofac locator.
            AutofacDependencyResolver resolver = new AutofacDependencyResolver(builder);
            Locator.SetLocator(resolver);

            // These .InitializeX() methods will add ReactiveUI platform 
            // registrations to your container. They MUST be present if
            // you *override* the default Locator.
            Locator.CurrentMutable.InitializeSplat();
            Locator.CurrentMutable.InitializeReactiveUI();

            Locator.CurrentMutable.RegisterConstant(new AvaloniaActivationForViewFetcher(), typeof(IActivationForViewFetcher));
            Locator.CurrentMutable.RegisterConstant(new AutoDataTemplateBindingHook(), typeof(IPropertyBindingHook));
            RxApp.MainThreadScheduler = AvaloniaScheduler.Instance;

            var container = builder.Build();
            resolver.SetLifetimeScope(container);
            BuildAvaloniaApp().Start(AppMain, args);
        }
    }
}
```

### Extension method

Now, this would look a lot nicer in an extension method similar to what we use to setup Splat and ReactiveUI:

```
    public static void InitializeAvalonia(this IMutableDependencyResolver resolver)
    {
        resolver.RegisterConstant(new AvaloniaActivationForViewFetcher(), typeof(IActivationForViewFetcher));
        resolver.RegisterConstant(new AutoDataTemplateBindingHook(), typeof(IPropertyBindingHook));
        RxApp.MainThreadScheduler = AvaloniaScheduler.Instance;
    }
```

and

```
    public static void Main(string[] args) {
        // Build a new Autofac container.
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
        builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()).AsImplementedInterfaces();

        // Use Autofac for ReactiveUI dependency resolution.
        // After we call the method below, Locator.Current and
        // Locator.CurrentMutable start using Autofac locator.
        AutofacDependencyResolver resolver = new AutofacDependencyResolver(builder);
        Locator.SetLocator(resolver);

        // These .InitializeX() methods will add ReactiveUI platform 
        // registrations to your container. They MUST be present if
        // you *override* the default Locator.
        Locator.CurrentMutable.InitializeSplat();
        Locator.CurrentMutable.InitializeReactiveUI();
        Locator.CurrentMutable.InitializeAvalonia();

        var container = builder.Build();
        resolver.SetLifetimeScope(container);
        BuildAvaloniaApp().Start(AppMain, args);
    }
```